# Save the state of the animations in the presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

is it possible to save the final state of a click animation?

You open the presentation, click on a button, something animates and this state can then be saved.
The next time the presentation is opened, you can see the last state of the animations.

I have a circuit diagram showing the points that are open or closed. Now you have to save this state of the points like.

Greeting
Steven

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible. As a workaround, you can make a screen shot of the end state of the animation and place that on a slide.

Comment: You could try PPspliT (http://www.maxonthenet.altervista.org/ppsplit.php) It's free and might do the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have now found a solution that is right for me ...

```
Sub ChangeControlSoft(ByRef oShp As Shape)

If oShp.Line.Parent.Rotation < 35 Then
    oShp.Line.Parent.Rotation = 35
ElseIf oShp.Line.Parent.Rotation = 35 Then
    oShp.Line.Parent.Rotation = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Maybe someone can still use it or improve it ;-)